# iOS payment, apple

Tags: ios, payment-gateway

I will create a iOS app for restaurants, so you can easily pay for your food via the app. So looking at the apple rules:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#physical-goods-and-services

So this is physical goods and not in-app purchases right?

My question is this: Can I choose ANY type of payment gateway, so I could just create a button in the app "Approve payment" and send this to my PHP backend, which will take care of all functionality regarding payments.

Or do I have to use Apple pay or go by some other rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use any payment method or methods you like. Apple mentions "Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry" as examples.

Customers may like if you support Apple Pay and they can pay just with their finger print, but there's no requirement for that.

Comment: After publishing the app, you are right. We can use any payment gateway we want, if we don't use in-app purchases. In-app purchases only takes apple pay or google wallet.